# how to render image in view. value of image  = byte[]. asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image

i have image value in database of type `"image"`.
in view saved under type `byte[]`
i want to show it as image in my asp.net mvc view. the best its just as image.
value if image is saved under `Model.ImageData.`

i tried to solve it like this:

```
<img height="450px" width="330px" src="<%= historyItem.ImageData %>" alt="image" />
```

but it doesnt work.
how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you have included the image data as part of your view model but the `<img>` tag expects an URL in the `src` attribute. Some browsers support [base64 embedded images](http://dean.edwards.name/my/base64-ie.html) to be put inside the HTML but I would recommend you to avoid this approach as the volume of your markup might grow.

So you will need a controller action which serves the image:

```
public ActionResult Image()
{
    byte[] imageData = ...
    return File(imageData, "image/png");
}
```

and then point the `src` attribute of the `img` tag to this controller action:

```
<img height="450px" width="330px" src="<%= Url.Action("Image") %>" alt="image" />
```

Comment: @Daniel A. White, haven't I? That's the second argument of the `File` method.

Comment: Well `imageData` might represent a JPG or GIF.

Comment: @Daniel A. White, sure, thought this was obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a separate action method that returns a `FileResult`.

There should be lots of different questions on Stackoverflow on the subject. Try something from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fileresult+mvc+image

Answer (score 0):

There may be a solution with embedded images. But aside from this, you need to create another action to download the image:

```
<img height="450px" width="330px" 
     src="<%: Url.Action("Image", "Controller", new { id=Model.ImageId }) %>"
     alt="image" />
```

In the controller class:

```
public FileResult Image(int id)
{
  byte[] imageData = getImageBytes(id);
  string mimeType = getMimeType(id);

  return new FileStreamResult(new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageData), mimeType );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on ASP.NET. That said, can you cast it to an Image or a Bitmap?

On a WinForm or in the ASP.NET code behind, it would look something like....

```
Image img = historyItem.ImageData as Image;
if (img != null) {
  // Do Something
}
```

~Joe