# Convert byte array to image on view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model that has byte array of image.
How convert byte array to image on view in mvc.net

Comment: Can you post some code? Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409576/how-to-render-image-in-view-value-of-image-byte-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I dont want use an action and i want convert in view

Comment: Browser normally download images, in a view you just need to specify url. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Let me attempt to make this clear:  What you are suggesting is not how HTTP works.  If you have an image, the aspx page being requested supplies a URL and only a URL for that image, and the browser makes a separate HTTP request for that image.  Therefore, you must supply your byte array data to the client in the form of response (via IHttpHandler) to that second request.  Your MVC view should only return a URL to the image, not the image itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are try to mix 2 resources: one is text/html type and another is image/jpeg. They are 2 different resources and should be requested separately. This means you cannot inject image in html.
It's better to return image as a file in separete Action, while Model field will provide view with a url of this Action.

Comment: See my answer, this solution will respond with any type of file you have saved in the Byte array, including image.  Note for image, you might want to change the MIME type. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777491/how-to-make-a-fileupload-interface-in-asp-net/6778935#6778935

Comment: It's better to return image as a file in separate Action:but this solution i should 2 connection to the database  .

Comment: Well there's not actually two connections, connection pooling will make sure that doesn't happen.  What you should be concerned about is retrieving binary image fields if you're not going to use them.  In your data access layer, separate the file's metadata (loaded into your view) from the file image-the varbinary(max) or blob column-(loaded by your IHttpHandler class).

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SaveImage(string path, byte[] img)
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
    FileStream fs = fi.OpenWrite();
    fs.Write(img, 0, img.Length);
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: Convert byte array to image on view